# Lost shell password: change user password from root

Tags: bash, passwords, root

I recently accidentally forgot my user password to my shell.  I know the root password.  How do I change the user password?

I figure it's something like

```
$su root
$passwd -[something] username
```

but I can't get it to work.  Halp pls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just "passwd mechko" I think, if you're logged as root ? tried it ? as existing password use roots or mechko's (in this case roots)

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I was looking at man pages even before I tried changing it so I got confused :-p

Comment: `passwd $user` as root doesn't require providing the current password.

Answer (score -1):

Old school, more powerful than necessary method:as root  empty the password field for that user in `/etc/passwd` or `/etc/shadow`. Then you can login and change the password.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind for next time :D

Comment: no, don't, unless you know how to fix it when you break things. the passwd command exists for a reason.